# check that argument is inside queting marks- python's click

Tags: python, click

I have a string argument the is being passed as a string in my click app. I need this argument to be surrounded with quoting marks or else there will be unexcpected behaviour , how can I force the user to give it in quoting marks?
Thanks!
edit:
to clarifey: the arguments are being passed thru the command lined and are parsed using the click package

Comment: If your script accepts only one argument you can raise an error if the user has passed multiple arguments.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How is it being passed? Using argparse?